# How to sum up all the elements with the same property in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList< Item>, and I want to do a function that sum all the quantity of the items with same code, then display all the items with the quantity.

```
public class Item{
    private String code;
    private int quantity;

    public Item(String InputCode, int InputQuantity)
    {
        this.code= InputCode;
        this.quantity = InputQuantity;
    }
}
```

Suppose i do the following

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
items.add(new Item("A01", 1));
items.add(new Item("A02", 1));
items.add(new Item("B05", 2));
items.add(new Item("A01", 3));
items.add(new Item("Z02", 2));
items.add(new Item("A02", 2));
display();
```

then the desired output is

```
A01 4
A02 3
B05 2
Z02 2
```

I have no idea, can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Hmm, you iterate the list; and use a `Map<String, Integer>` to count?

Comment: Well, with that `Item` class, you don't -- not outside of `Item`'s code, anyway, as `quantity` is private and there are no accessors...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this with streams:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

...

Map<String, Integer> map = items.stream()
                               .collect(groupingBy(Item::getCode,
                                   summingInt(Item::getQuantity)));
```

Assuming your class has these getters:

```
public class Item {
    ...
    public String getCode() {...}
    public int getQuantity() {...}
}
```

This maps the item codes, `A01`, `A02`, etc. to the respective sums of their quantities.

---

You can get the output, sorted by the code, with:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    .forEachOrdered((e) -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue()));
```

Note: Using `.forEachOrdered(System.out::println)` instead, produces output like `A01=4`, which is almost the same as the example you gave, and a little simpler than the above.

Answer (score 2):

Create a map where string being the code and int will be quantity. Iterate over the list of item check if map contains the key if yes, add the quantity else add new key value pair.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new Hashmap<String, Integer>();
for(Item item : items){
    if(map.containsKey(item.code)){
        int q = map.get(item.code) + item.quantity;
        map.put(item.code, q);
    } else {
        map.put(item.code, item.quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: If java 8 is available, this could be simplyfied by using [compute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#compute-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using the Java 8 `Stream API` and a `TreeMap`:

The `TreeMap` by default keeps its keys sorted according to the comparable natural ordering.

*Required imports*

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.summingInt;       
import java.util.TreeMap;
```

*Sample code*

```
Map<String, Integer> result = items.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Item::getCode, TreeMap::new, summingInt(Item::getQtd)));

result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
```

*Output*

```
A01 4
A02 3
B05 2
Z02 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

1. Create a `Map<String,Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>()`;
2. Iterate the list and add code as `Key` of a Map and quantity as `Value`.

Eg:

```
Map<String,Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>()
for(Item item: items){
   Integer count=countMap.get(item.getCode())
   // if null then add quantity and code
   // eg: countMap.put(item.getCode(),item.getQuantity())
   // if not null countMap.put(item.getCode(),count+item.getQuantity()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the stream framework and esp. the examples in the Collectors class. The "Compute sum of salaries by department" can be easily adopted to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Map<String, Integer> maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Item item;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            item = items.get(i);
            maps.put(item.getCode(), maps.containsKey(item.getCode()) ? item.getQuantity()+ + maps.get(item.getCode()) : item.getQuantity());   
        }
        item = null;
```

// Item Class

```
public class Item{
    private String code;
    private int quantity;

    public Item(String InputCode, int InputQuantity)
    {
        this.code= InputCode;
        this.quantity = InputQuantity;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a solution from myside in java6. i have added getters and setters in your Item class and implements compraable on base of itemcode.

hope it may help you.

Modified Item Class.

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    private String code;
    private int quantity;

    public Item(String InputCode, int InputQuantity) {
        this.code = InputCode;
        this.quantity = InputQuantity;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.getCode().compareTo(o.getCode());
    }

}
```

And method to get the desired list :

```
List<Item> getDesiredList(List<Item> itemList) {
        List<Item> tempList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        // sort list to maintain order
        Collections.sort(itemList);
        String itemCode = null;
        int quantity = 0;
        Item itemObj = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            if (itemCode == null || itemCode.equals(itemList.get(i).getCode())) {
                quantity = quantity + itemList.get(i).getQuantity();
            } else {
                itemObj = new Item(itemCode, quantity);
                if (tempList.contains(itemObj)) {
                    tempList.remove(itemObj);
                }
                tempList.add(itemObj);
                quantity = 0;
                quantity = quantity + itemList.get(i).getQuantity();
            }

            itemCode = itemList.get(i).getCode();

            if (i == itemList.size() - 1) {
                itemObj = new Item(itemCode, quantity);
                tempList.add(itemObj);
            }
        }

        return tempList;
    }
```

Hope it may help you.